# Run specific step in sql job without running the entire job

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Job name ' TEST' which is having 3 steps.

There is a requirement to run only the Step 2, But when I right click on job name and click on start job at step and start the job from step 2 it runs the step 3 as well.

Even when I run the job like

```
EXEC msdb..sp_start_job @job_name = 'Test', @step_name='2'
```

It still run the step 3 which I don't want.

Is there a way in this scenario. I dont want to add step-2 in a seperate job and run it seperately.

Comment: how about temporary amend to job to quit after step 2. Or copy step 2 and execute in a new query window

Answer (score 1):

Starting a job at a specific step bypasses the previous ones, not the subsequent. Also, to my knowledge, you may not bypass the next ones in any way, or disable a step.

For a temporary solution, I'd recommend moving your desired step (2) to the end, and then execute starting at it.

Comment: I thought the same as well!

Answer (score 1):

You can't bypass the next step. You will need to either move down the step or create a separate SQL job to run the given step.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to edit the step's "on success action".

First, open the Job Properties, select the relevant step, and select "Edit":
[image]

Next, go to the "Advanced" tab and change "On success action" from "Go to the next step" to "Quit the job reporting success".

[image]